# Not able to configure SonarQube with Azure SQL with authentication=ActiveDirectoryManagedIdentity

Tags: sonarqube

**Context:** Trying to setup SonarQube with Azure SQL DB **without hardcoding any user and password anywhere in the SonarQube host**

- SonarQube version : ***10.1.0*** (evaluation version)
- Java :
  `java 17.0.7 2023-04-18 LTS Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+8-LTS-224) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.7+8-LTS-224, mixed mode, sharing)`
- SonarQube Host: Windows Server 2019 Datacenter (in Azure)
- SonarQube HOST is configured with System Assigned Managed Identity
- Azure SQL DB configured with:

  - Azure SQL Database with Azure AD Authentication
  - SonarQube HOST name is configured as contained user
  - Connectivity from SonarQube Host and SQL DB with Managed Identity is verified and working with SSMS (installed in SonarQube host)
- SonarQube property files:

  - `sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://my-sqlserver.database.windows.net:1433;database=ms-sql-db-sonar;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;user=<SONAR VM IdentityId>;Authentication=`***`ActiveDirectoryManagedIdentity`***`;`
- Microsoft SQL JDBC Driver version (built-in with SonarQube): mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11
- SonarQube is executing as of now in a Console mode

**Problem statement:**

Facing the following Issue when we are starting the sonar by executing StartSonar from (<SONAR INSTALLED PATH>\bin\windows-x86-64\):

```
2023.07.14 21:41:33 ERROR web[][c.z.h.p.HikariPool] HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Failed to load MSAL4J Java library for performing ActiveDirectoryManagedIdentity authentication.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getFedAuthToken(SQLServerConnection.java:5642)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.onFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:5618)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.processFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:5463)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onFedAuthInfo(tdsparser.java:311)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:131)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:42)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:6490)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:5068)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:5002)

......
......
......
```

**Query:**

- Is at all SonarQube supports the "***ActiveDirectoryManagedIdentity***" Authentication mode with Azure SQL DB?
- If the above is supported, Can anybody help me to describe the steps to configure it properly?
- If at all the above is not supported, Is there any simple way to completely secure the user and password information of SQL Connection in SonarQube? As of now, it is hardcoded in sonar.properties file.

Tried the following already refereeing different web sites, with my limited knowledge in Java:

- Downloaded the Microsoft MSAL4J jar file (msal4j-1.13.9) from Maven and placed it inside "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin", added "CLASSPATH" variables with entire jar file path
- Downloaded the azure-identity-1.7.0 jar file from Maven and placed it inside "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin", added "CLASSPATH" variables with entire jar file path
- Restarted system after all the required adjustments
- Still no luck

Comment: Hello, I found the solution by myself. But still not sure about the root cause.

Actually what I found that built-in mssql driver “mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11” that shipped with SonarQube 10.1.0 (evaluation version) was NOT working as per the above context/configurations.

Instead, I downloaded the mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar from Maven and then only it worked for SonarQube 10.1.0 (evaluation version).

Similarly, for SonarQube 9.9 (LTS) (evaluation version) => mssql-jdbc-11.2.2.jre17.jar driver is Only working (instead of the built-in drivers)

Comment: Adjust the connection string in sonar properties like the following:
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://tcp:[[server name]].database.windows.net,1433;database=[[db name]];encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMSI

Comment: Saved me a bunch of time to pick the right version of mssql-jdbc. I do confirm that even 12.2.4.jre11 do not work with SonarQube 9.9. I got the same error MSAL4J. No issue with 11.2.2.jre17